# How to optimize query when operating with 1million++ data transaction details using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to make a report on the best-selling items and in the `transaction_solid_details` table, there are 1 million+ data and I want to implement this data to the datatable server side. I am using Laravel query builder to get desired results from the database. The following query works perfectly but takes too much time to get results. Can you please help me optimize this query to make it faster?

```
$start = ($request->start) ? $request->start : '2022-04-01';
$end = ($request->end) ? $request->end : Carbon::now()->toDateString();

$bestSellingTransactions = DB::table('transaction_liquid_details')
                           ->select('transaction_liquid_details.item_id', 'items.barcode', 
                             'items.name as item_name', 'item_units.name as item_unit_name',
                             'categories.name as category_name', 
                              DB::raw('SUM(transaction_liquid_details.quantity * transaction_liquid_details.parfume) as total_sold'),
                              DB::raw('SUM(transaction_liquid_details.total) as total_price'))
                           ->join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'transaction_liquid_details.item_id')
                           ->leftJoin('item_units', 'item_units.id', 'items.item_unit_id')
                           ->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', 'items.category_id')
                           ->leftJoin('transactions', 'transactions.id', 'transaction_liquid_details.transaction_id')
                           ->groupBy('transaction_liquid_details.item_id', 'items.barcode', 'items.name', 'item_units.name', 'categories.name')
                           ->orderBy('total_sold', 'DESC')
                           ->whereBetween('transactions.created_at', [$start, $end . " 23:59:59"])
                           ->where('transactions.status', $this->FINISHED_TRANSACTION_STATUS)
                           ->get();
```

And this is the table structure.

For `items` table.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npA8a.png)

For `transaction_liquid_details` table.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFRM9.png)

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (The images fail to show what indexes exist.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how fast you want it and how much work you're willing to put in.

Instead of doing a bunch of sums, joins, group bys, order bys, etc. it could be faster to have cached database results. One simple way is to create a bestselling_transactions table with the desired results which you can schedule this to be filled via cron or something. Then the next time someone wants the data, they can just query that table directly without having the database redo the computation. You can look at Laravel's caching if you want to stick with Laravel's way of doing things: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache

If this still takes too long, you can look at denormalizing your table structure.

You can use the EXPLAIN command (or something similar depending on what database you're using) to figure out what is making your query slow.

If it makes sense to, you can look at OLAP databases like Clickhouse which are often much faster than the more traditional OLTP databases like MySQL for reading large datasets.